# Form submits in FireFox when any button on page is clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, button, form-submit

First time using Asp.net-mvc and originally followed the NerdDinner tutorial.  My form submit button looks like this:

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
```

I've now added another button to the page with jQuery code attached.  It works in IE, but when I test in FireFox the form submits.  I tried adding another button, this time with no attached jQuery code and the same thing happens.  When the button is clicked, the form submits.

```
<button id="random-button">Do Nothing</button>
```

Why does the standard `button` element submit the form in Firefox?

Comment: Could you post your jQuery code relative to these buttons?

Comment: It happens for the second button which has no jQuery code at all.  It happens when I delete all jQuery from the page.

Comment: Try disabling javascript in Firefox. Does the form still submits? If the answer is no then the problem is definitely in your jQuery code.

Comment: It happens with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recall that Firefox defaults a <button> to a submit button.  If you use

```
 <button type="button" id="random-button">Do Nothing</button>
```

it should solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to have broken my jQuery, but it has solved the submit problem.  I'll have to fix my jQuery now.

Comment: You are welcome.  It's one of those things that you remember for the rest of your life the first time you run into it.  Have fun collecting these tidbits.

Comment: ... and a baffling problem on my own page is suddenly explained.  Thank you much.  God, I love this site.